# Match query for full text indexing not returning complete results in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a query in my project where I have to search for records with like query with wildcard search.

Following is the query:

```
Select * from table_name where Col_name like '% text %';
```

Now in above query normal indexing wouldn't work. So, I have used full text indexing here in `MyISAM` mysql table.

After which my query modifies like as follows

```
Select * from table_name where MATCH(Col_name) AGAINST('text' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

First query gives me 150000 records where as second query gives me only 3000 records.

Please guide me how to get all records which I am getting in first query as well in second query as well.

Answer (score 0):

Full Text Search indexes are based on individual words, that means the phrase `row with texts`  or `textWithOtherCharactersAround` will no be returned in query result.

The `like` operator finds in the entire field value according to wildcards.

Comment: But this link says it will give all the records-http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html